# When building Qt programs, how could I use former qmake flags in cmake?

Tags: qt, cmake, build, bluetooth

When building former version of qtconnectivity lib, official site said I could use `-native-win32-bluetooth` to enable native bluetooth API, like `qmake -- -native-win32-bluetooth`, but how could I use this flag when building the new version lib with cmake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you talk about CMake, I assume you talk about Qt 6. Qt 6 doesn't support the native Win32 Bluetooth API anymore, see also https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-dev/whatsnew62.html :

> Win32 backend was removed. As a consequence, there is no longer support for Qt Bluetooth using MinGW.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I need! BTW, what should I do to use CMake with other qmake flags like `qmake -xxx`?

Comment: That really depends on the qmake option in question.